# How to save a image on server with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working in a little web app that generates an base64 image, I'm using blob to put it back into a file (is a .png but I haven't renamed it yet), now I'm trying to save it on my sever Any ideas or different approaches?

This is the script:

```
var img = document.getElementById("MyPix");
    img.onclick = function() {

        var image_data = atob(img.src.split(',')[1]);
        var arraybuffer = new ArrayBuffer(image_data.length);
        var view = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
        for (var i=0; i<image_data.length; i++) {
            view[i] = image_data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
        }
        try {
            var blob = new Blob([arraybuffer], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
        } catch (e) {
            var bb = new (window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder);
            bb.append(arraybuffer);
            var blob = bb.getBlob('application/octet-stream');
        }

        var url = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);

        valor = (document.getElementById("link").value = url)

        location.href = valor; 

    };
```

I'm not very good with js so if you want to have a better idea visit the project [clicking here](http://forbesstudio.com/apps/post_card/index2.html) its all javascript so just see source code.

Comment: What is your server running?

Comment: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix) PHP/4.4.6

Comment: AIEEEE! That's ancient -- PHP 4.4.6 was released in March of **2007**. Before you do anything else, get a better web host.

Answer (score 1):

you can't save to your server with just client-side JavaScript. Form the data you want to save in Javascript, then POST that to your server with a call to a page that you write that can turn POST data into a file on your filesystem, so in your case a .php file with code that looks for `$_POST` data and then writes that to file. After making sure it's safe, because anyone will be able to post data to that page, not just people using your webpage.